# Get RabbitMQ run automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I'm running RabbitMQ on a EC2 machine. To start RabbitMQ working I type:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
```

This starts ok and everything works. My issue is when I disconnect from the shell so does Rabbit.

**How to I get rabbitmq-server to run automatically and without having to keep open my .ssh shell?**

I'm running on a Ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the process detached as the [docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmq-server.1.man.html) state.

```
sudo rabbitmq-server -detached
```

Comment: Is this something I have to do on every start up?

Comment: yes, if you don't want to type all that every time, you could put it in a shell script